# Using grepl in a string replace function in R Programming

Tags: r, grepl

Trying to create function using grepl to replace a word in a string.

```
Airport_ID<-c("3001","3002","3003","3004")
Airport_Name<-c("Adelaide Airport GOODFIND","GOODFIND DTS Land Airport Land ADTS",
                "Washington DTS INC GOODFINDAirport DTSUpdated",
                "DALLAS Airport TDS GOODFIND")

TF_Data<-data.frame(Airport_ID,Airport_Name)
```

Created the below function

```
STR_Manip_F_M_L_V1 <- function(data=NULL,by_text1="GOODFIND",by_text2="Updated") {
  if(!require(glue)) {library(glue) }
  
  TFD <- TF_Data %>% 
    filter(grepl(glue("^{by_text1} "),Airport_Name) | 
             grepl(glue(" \\({by_text1}\\) "),Airport_Name) |
             grepl(glue(" \\({by_text1}\\$"),Airport_Name) )
  
  TFD$Airport_Name <- str_replace(TFD$Airport_Name = glue("^{by_text1} "),replacement = glue("^{by_text2} ") )
  
  return(TFD)
}

Error :
Error: object 'TFD' not found.
```

Comment: FYI, `if(!require(glue)) {library(glue) }` is broken: when `!require(.)` returns false, it means that the package is not available to be loaded, so `library(glue)` will fail and error. That whole statement can be logically reduced to `library(glue)` (no `if` conditional). I think you intend `if (!require(glue)) { install.packages("glue"); library(glue); }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems here:

1. You define `data` in the function arguments but use `TFD_Data`. This is not causing an error but is a logical mistake, making reproducibility and troubleshooting a bit more difficult.
2. Your use of `str_replace` is not quite right, don't "name" the arguments as you've done here. (Or ... perhaps just change your `=` to a comma ...).

Since you're using `dplyr` earlier, I think it's good to stay in that mode ... try this:

```r
STR_Manip_F_M_L_V1 <- function(data=NULL,by_text1="GOODFIND",by_text2="Updated") {
  out <- data %>% 
    filter(grepl(glue("^{by_text1} "),Airport_Name) | 
             grepl(glue(" \\({by_text1}\\) "),Airport_Name) |
             grepl(glue(" \\({by_text1}\\$"),Airport_Name) ) %>%
    mutate(Airport_Name = str_replace(Airport_Name, paste0("^", by_text1), by_text2))
  out
}

STR_Manip_F_M_L_V1(TF_Data)
#   Airport_ID                       Airport_Name
# 1       3002 Updated DTS Land Airport Land ADTS
```